# jQuery Deferred struggle

Tags: jquery, deferred

I'm struggling to get deferred to work how I would like it. Here is my test scenario:

```js
function myFn(val) {

  var d = $.Deferred();

  console.log("starting: " + val);

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('timeover:' + val);
    d.resolve();
  }, 1000);

  console.log("ending: " + val);
  return d.promise();
}

test = myFn(1).done(myFn(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The output is

```
starting: 1
ending: 1
starting: 2
ending: 2
timeover: 1
timeover: 2
```

where what I would like is:

```
starting: 1
timeover: 1
ending: 1
starting: 2
timeover: 2
ending: 2
```

Where have I misunderstood the deferred?

Comment: Simplest solution here would be `test = myFn(1).done(()=>{myFn(2)});`

Comment: `test = myFn(1).done(function() { myFn(2); });` See the linked question's answers for details. (That question's about `setTimeout`, but the problem is the same as your `done`. `.done(myFn(2))` **calls** `myFn(2)` and passes its return value into `done`, just like `foo(bar())` **calls** `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.)

Comment: Thanks - both worked perfectly.